# How do you make an object be limited to the boundaries of a Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently making a Space Invaders type game using C# Windows Forms. When creating the laser cannon which the user controls, I want them to move left and right, shooting lasers.  This is my current code for the movement so far:

```
enter code here
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Move
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Left - 1);
                Application.DoEvents();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Left + 1);
                Application.DoEvents();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }




        }
      }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

However, I'm having an issue with this; if the image goes too far, it goes out of the boundaries of the form but I want it to do is bounce off and go the other way.

I tried doing this but to no avail, it only moves by a pixel but I think it's a good step(right?...):

```
if(pictureBox1.Location == new Point(300,300))
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Left - 1);
            }
```

Like how do I get the correct X,Y coordinates of the whole form so I could tell it to go the other way as well as actually getting it to move?

Comment: This is a bit confusing. You want pressing up (?!?) to move right until you hit the end of the screen and then you want up to move you left? You shouldn't bounce of the side of the screen, you should stick to the side of the screen. Just test the coordinates against the boundaries of the contain and _don't_ move if it takes you outside. Otherwise I don't even know how you expect people to be able to move left again since up now moves right, what does down do?

Comment: Be careful with `Application.DoEvents()`.  It can have nasty side-effects.  If you think you need it, then you're doing something wrong in your drawing.  As to your question, just check your object position within the client `Bounds`.

Comment: why new point(300,300)?
you can check boundary by its width and height

Comment: And absolutely what @DonBoitnott said about `DoEvents`. Any time you need `DoEvents` you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @MattBurland yeah I know it's weird, only experimenting with it until I get it to work. I should probably change it now. In this case up = right, down = left. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @DonBoitnott I'm sorry but I'm not that of an expert at C# ,how do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest X and Y position for a picture box to stay inside the form is 0.

The largest X a picture box can go to is `Form.ClientSize.Width - pictureBox.Size.Width`

The largest Y a picture box can go is `Form.ClientSize.Height - pictureBox.Size.Height`.

Check all of these things in an if statement. If either the X or Y of the picture box is outside of the ranges, don't move the picture box, otherwise, *do* move it.